# how to see the Table structure in the Query Analyzer MS SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am trying to check the table structure of given table in Query Analyzer.

I am trying to see the anything equivalent Of **Describe in Mysql** in **SQL server**

I found **sp_help**, but that gives me more than what I expect.

Comment: how much more is it giving you?

Comment: Like Row Gide Col, Data located on filegroup, identity..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT * 
FROM   information_schema.columns
WHERE  table_name = 'YourTable'
```

[sp_columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176077.aspx) also works but that's 2005 and up and you reference "Query Analyzer" which is for 2000

Comment: @Frix, this gives me the table informtion, How to get the Column informations for the given table

Comment: @Harigm doh, sorry about that I updated the answer. It columns not tables. The where clause is right though